Chain falls behind rear sprockets - safeguards?
From time to time, my chain falls off the rear sprockets, and then gets stuck between sprockets and spokes.
Apparently this is because my gears are losing their adjustment. When I re-adjust them every 1-2 months, the problem does not occur.
However: As an additional safeguard, I would like to install some kind of permanent mechanical solution. Is there anything you can do to prevent the chain from ever getting in there? For example, some kind of plastic disk mounted to the sprockets or spokes?

The main device to stop this is the limit screw on your rear derailleur. I see two possibilities:

You're only adjusting the cable tension and the limit screw has never been set right - in that case set it correctly.
The limit screw is creeping. First try taking it right out and degreasing both the screw and the hole it goes into.  If that doesn't work, a single drop of light threadlocker might be needed.  But I'd be wary of that because the limit screw doesn't use a very chunky tool and the head is prone to rounding off.  As an alternative, after  adjusting it, a drop of nail polish on and next to the screw  may secure it, but will certainly reveal if it moves.

While you're working in that area, just check nothing is wobbly, such as a loose derailleur mounting screw.

+1, limit screw should be all you need. If the chain still keeps falling into the spokes there is a problem somewhere else. Bent derailleur hanger or maybe loose cassette, bearing play or loose derailleur (though all of those should be easy to diagnose).

@Michael loose derailleur is a good thought - I'll add that in assuming you don't mind

Some frames are just a bit more flexy, so a hard pedal push, like when going up a hill, can be enough to cause a ghost-shift.   If rider is already in the big cog, there isn't a next gear to ghost-shift onto and hence badness ensues.

@Criggie: But even with a ghost shift you’d still hit the limit screw, no? And the derailleur shouldn’t flex under heavy load relative to the cassette.

IME (@Michael) even ghost shifting caused by a bent axle  isn't enough to drop the chain, but in principle because the limit screws are in the derailleur anything that changes the relationship between the derailleur and the wheel could

THIS. Also, gears shouldn't need adjusting so frequently. Either something is moving that shouldn't (barrel adjuster at either end, cable where it terminates in the derailleur, clamp-on cable stops) or something's deforming (cable, cable housing).


Yes, it's often called a "dork disk". Any bike shop can install one for you, and will probably have some lying around.

Is Dork Disk the official name or is it the name the fast/confident riders use to insult people who use one?

"spoke protector" is the name I've seen when these are marketed. I believe "dork disk" was originally meant to be disparaging, but now there's folks that encourage its use and also call it that.

I'd like to point out that these often cause more problems than they solve.

Dork Disks have their place, but they are a bandaid. The route cause (as discussed elsewhere) should be addressed. Main concern with Dork Disks is with today's tight tolerances, the derailleur moving far enough to drop the chain into the gap between spokes and cluster is very close to getting caught in spokes. Derailleur getting caught in spokes is Ghostbusters movie "Don't cross the streams" kind of bad...
